# PIL Python, mask over image without losing a certain color of the original image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

With PIL, I want to mask an image over other image.

However, I want to keep the black outline of original image.

Example:
[image]

Below is the code I've tried. I have different shapes (Circle, Heart, Triangle) All with black outlines. I want to put the mask over those shapes without losing the original image's black outline, but I'm unsure of how to do so.

```
whead = whead.resize((200, 240))
data = np.array(whead)  
red, green, blue, alpha = data.T 
white_areas = (red == 222) & (blue == 222) & (green == 222)
data[..., :-1][white_areas.T] = ImageColor.getrgb(headhex)
whead2 = Image.fromarray(data)
img.paste(whead2, (0, 30), whead2)

facemask1 = facemask1.resize((200, 240))
data = np.array(facemask1)  
red, green, blue, alpha = data.T 
white_areas = (red == 23) & (blue == 0) & (green == 255)
data[..., :-1][white_areas.T] = ImageColor.getrgb(facemask1hex)
facemask12 = Image.fromarray(data)
img.paste(facemask12, (0, 30), whead2)
```

Comment: If you make the orange part of the mask white you could multiply the two images to make the border dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for `PIL` solution, try `PIL.ImageChops.multiply`.

Make sure you color your image white only. And you need to make your background transparent - if your tool don't support alpha channel, lots of web-based background removers are out there to help you.

---

#### Files

mask.png
[image]

outline.png
[image]

---

#### Code

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

source = Image.open("outline.png")
source = source.convert("RGBA")

mask = Image.open("mask.png")
mask = mask.convert("RGBA")

output = ImageChops.multiply(source, mask)
output.save("output.png")
```

You need to match image mode, for i.e. *mask.png* is on mode *RGB* while *outline.png* is on *RGBA* and will cause `ValueError: images do not match`.

output.png
[image]